# Logstash Not Receiving TCP Data

Tags: python, elasticsearch, tcp, logstash

I am shipping monitored data as JSON from Python. I have tested whether the data is actually being sent outside of Logstash and it is successfully sending and being received. With Logstash the input is showing no signs of being received with the TCP input plugin.

Here is my configuration:

```
input{
   tcp{
     port => 55556
     codec => json
   }
}

output{
   elasticsearch {
   hosts => ['localhost:9200']
   sniffing => true
   index => "test2"
  document_type => "health"
  }
}
```

Verbose debugging doesn't show anything other than the basic output for logstash spinning up and connecting to the elasticsearch output specified. I'm under the impression that it might have something to do with the message being sent being ignored due to formatting.

Example message:

```
{"@fields": {"test": "test"}, "@message": {"doc_type": "sys_status", "PSUs": 2, "index": "shipper", "hostname": "client1", "CPUs": 2, "System": 4, "point_of_contact": "Tom Perry", "DIR": 4}, "@tags": ["test"]}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use tcp to log directly from your app in this way. This may cause your application to freeze if logstash is down.

Comment: @jordanm What would you recommend, then? I am handling a closed connection, message failing to be sent, etc so it doesn't cause the app to fail. Just tries to reconnect and places the message in a queue until the connection is up again.